# Finding a relation in 3NF but not in BCNF

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf, bcnf

I've been reading many different sources on how to differentiate relations that are in 3NF/BCNF. And I've so far this is my understanding...

I will use this relation as an example...

`R = {A, B, C, D, E}`

and

`F = {A -> B, B C - > E, E D -> A}`.

Firstly we must find the keys of the relation. [I used this video to help me do that.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1DNVWKeQ_w) And I got

`Keys = {ACD, BCD, CDE}`

Now to make sure `R` is in **BCNF**, we must make sure that the left hand side of every functional dependency in `F` is one of the `Keys`. We instantly know this is not the case, because the first FD is `A -> B` and `A` is not one of the keys. **So it is not in BCNF.**

Now to make sure `R` is in **3NF**, we must make sure that the left hand side of every functional dependency in `F` is one of the `Keys` **OR** the right hand side of every functional dependency in `F` is a subset of one of the `Keys`. If you look at the right hand side of every FD, they are `B`, `E` and `A`. These are each a subset of a `Key`, so this means that **it is in 3NF**.

So this is one of the *rare* cases (according to wiki) where a relation is in `3NF` but **not** in `BCNF`. Is this method correct? Is it reliable? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yep, you did everything right.

Comment: you may want to check out this: http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you need to learn superkeys, candidate keys, and primary attributes.

However, this rule of thumb helps:

> A 3NF table that does not have multiple overlapping candidate keys is
>   guaranteed to be in BCNF.

In other words, if the **candidate keys** in a 3NF relation are

- all atomic, or
- non-atomic but non-overlapping,

it is guaranteed that the relation is in BCNF.

The simplest relation which violates BCNF but meets 3NF has the following functional dependencies:

`A,B -> C      C -> B`

In this case, candidate keys are `(A,B)` and `(A,C)`. 
It meets 3NF because

- the right-hand-side of all functional dependencies is a **primary attribute**.

It violates BCNF because

- `C -> B`, but the left-hand-side is not a **superkey**.

Answer (score 0):

BCNF:

> X->Y where Y can be **prime** or **non-prime**
>   Here,X *must* be a **super key**

**3NF**:

> X->Y where Y is **non-prime**
>   then,
>   X *must* be a **super key**
>    *else*
>   X *need not* be **super key**

Hope,this helps

Comment: These are not clear or correct. Look at some textbook definitions, or even wikipedia.

Comment: The definitions are vague. For example, for BCNF you could simply state that X must be a super key. The definition of 3NF is correct, but this is the most complicated way of describing it!

Answer (score -1):

Basically we remove all the transitive dependencies in non prime attributes in the 3NF but there can be dependencies among the prime attributes(where prime attributes are on left and right side both). This happens only when there are multiple overlapping candidate keys. This is when the relation is not in BCNF and further normalisation is possible by removing the redundancy due to those dependencies among prime attributes.